# Razor page form submission disable submit button but unable to enable it if form has client validation

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using razor pages, i have a simple form submission

```
 <form method="post" onsubmit="btnSave.disabled = true; btnSave.value = 'Please Wait..'">
     <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save"  /> 
 </form>
```

This works fine for my form submission, but i have some dropdown lists i am validating with in the form using Razor page validation as such

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

Which is the _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml content

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

So if i hit a validation error on one of my dropdown lists the submit button stays diabled and says "Please Wait.." , i can't figure how to if a validation fails for the _ValidationScriptsPartial how to re-enable my button and have it say "Save" again instead of "Please Wait.." so the user can resubmit ?

Comment: Why don't you use server side rendering?For example,you can have a field named error and you render that  page again with that error  if validation fails.

Comment: i did :) should have thought of that, thx